# Primefaces p:chips, existe alguma forma de iniciar a lista de tags sem valor nenhum?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Em minha tela, preciso que a lista das tags no componente chips inicie vazia e quando tiver valores preciso que sejam setados como tags, porém quando tento iniciar uma lista vazia de tags, o componente inicia uma tag em branco no campo, eu preciso que o campo seja iniciado em branco, sem nenhuma tag...

```
public String getCanInteresses() {
    return canInteresses;
}

public void setCanInteresses(String canInteresses) {
    this.canInteresses = canInteresses;
}

//REVISAR
public List<String> getCanListInteresses() {
    return Arrays.asList(canInteresses);
}

public void setCanListInteresses(List<String> canInteresses) {
    this.canInteresses = StringUtil.join(canInteresses, ",");
}
```

XHTML

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3" layout="grid">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Interesse" />
                                <p:chips id="tagsInteresse" value="#{curriculoBean.crudObj.canListInteresses}" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Adicionar" icon="#{icon.adicionar}" process="@this :form1:tagsInteresse" update=":form1:tagsInteresse" oncomplete="$(function(){PrimeFaces.focus('form1:tagsInteresse');});" />
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:panelGrid>
```

O campo inicia com null e mesmo fazendo o teste se for null e setando vazio, ele cria uma tag sem nenhum valor dentro

[image: O campo inicia com null e mesmo fazendo o teste se for null e setando vazio, ele cria uma tag sem nenhum valor dentro]

**Preciso somente que o campo inicie sem tag nenhuma, somente quando já possuir valores vinculados**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na lógica de instanciar a lista com valores dentro:

```
return Arrays.asList(canInteresses); // Se canInteresses for null, a lista será criada com um elemento nulo dentro
```

Acredito que seria melhor você possuir um atributo na sua classe conforme abaixo:

```
private List<String> interesses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Você poderia carregar o valor através de um método para ser chamado sempre que precisar verificar e atualizar a lista:

```
public void carregarInteresses() {
    interesses.clear(); 
    if(canInteresses != null && !canInteresses.isEmpty()) {
        interesses.addAll(Arrays.asList(canInteresses.split(",")));
    }
}
```

E no momento que você for persistir, ou tratar a String `canInteresses` você aplica o tratamento `StringUtil.join(interesses, ",")` como vem fazendo.

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Só uma coisa, eu chamaria o carregarInteresses onde? no xhtml?

Comment: Eu chamaria no managed bean, em um `@PostConstruct`, ou após carregar os dados da tela, ou em qualquer lugar em que você queira sincronizar os chips de `interesses` com o `canInteresses`

Comment: Não tinha pensando nessa hipótese, obrigado!